# boot2docker mount windows share

Tags: windows, unix, cifs, shared-directory, boot2docker

I am running boot2docker on windows and I am trying to access a shared folder on my host from the VM.

I have executed the following

```
  sudo mkdir /mnt/docktest
  sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.24.75/dock /mnt/docktest -o user=username
     mount: mounting //192.168.24.75/dock on /mnt/docktest/ failed: Permission denied
  sudo mount -t smbfs //192.168.24.75/dock /mnt/docktest -o username=username
     mount: mounting //192.168.24.75/dock on /mnt/docktest/ failed: No such device
```

My host (192.168.24.75) has the folder "dock" shared with access to the user I am supplying.

I have tried adding the password and domain in the command as well to no avail (even though I would rather not have to)

Note: I would rather not share the folder using the VirtualBox shared folders as it would restrict me to be between the host and it's own vm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution was to install `cifs-utils` using `tce-load`

Comment: How exactly did you do that? with `tce-load -wi cifs-utils` ?

Comment: I first used wget to download the file (found a download link online) then installed it locally using tce-load -i <filename>